# Perform function for all c:\users\*\AppData\Local

Tags: powershell

Got the following script that I thought would happily update the specified .ini file in each `C:\users\*\AppData\Local\Greeentram` folder individually.

```
function Set-OrAddIniValue {
    Param(
        [string]$FilePath,
        [hashtable]$keyValueList
    )

    $content = Get-Content $FilePath

    $keyValueList.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        if ($content -match "^$($_.Key)=") {
            $content= $content -replace "^$($_.Key)=(.*)", "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"
        } else {
            $content += "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"
        }
    }

    $content | Set-Content $FilePath
}

Set-OrAddIniValue -FilePath "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Greentram\SDA_Apps.ini"  -keyValueList @{
    UserName = "Dcebtcv7[[G"
    UserEmail = "x}tpwpjmkxmvkYjmklzmx7zv7lr"
    UserNo = "*++*(+"
    UserKey = "^X(_0[*_/0L)\_0,U,-"
    KEM = "H10"
}
```

What it seems to be doing is somehow combining all the .INI files together and creating a new .INI file for each user.

I have wrongly assumed that `C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Greentram\SDA_Apps.ini` would work.

I only want to update or add these specific values to each .INI file.

```
Set-OrAddIniValue -FilePath "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Greentram\SDA_Apps.ini"  -keyValueList @{
    UserName = "Dcebtcv7[[G"
    UserEmail = "x}tpwpjmkxmvkYjmklzmx7zv7lr"
    UserNo = "*++*(+"
    UserKey = "^X(_0[*_/0L)\_0,U,-"
    KEM = "H10"
}
```

Comment: `results = @(); gci c:\users\* -Directory | % {$results += "$($_.FullName)\AppData\Local\Greentram\SDA_Apps.ini"}` You might also want to exclude certain folders like "Default" or "Allusers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `Set-OrAddIniValue` doesn't handle wildcards in paths.

```
$content = Get-Content $FilePath
...
$content | Set-Content $FilePath
```

The first statement reads the content of all matching files into a single array. The second statement then writes the entire modified content to all matching files. (How would it decide which content belongs to which file?)

You can either call your function for each file individually:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Greentram\SDA_Apps.ini" | ForEach-Object {
    Set-OrAddIniValue -FilePath $_.FullName -keyValueList ...
}
```

or change your function so that it does the enumeration internally:

```
function Set-OrAddIniValue {
    Param(
        [string]$FilePath,
        [hashtable]$keyValueList
    )

    Get-ChildItem $FilePath | Where-Object {
        -not $_.PSIsContainer   # process only files
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_.FullName
        $content = Get-Content $file
        ...
        $content | Set-Content $file
    }
}
```

On PowerShell v3 and newer you can use `Get-ChildItem -File` instead of piping the object list through `Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer}`.